# Android Input box background disapearing

Tags: android, css, mobile

We have styled an search text input box on our site with a background image,  all looks great until you click on it using android and the background disapears whilst typing, once typing is completed the image returns!!

Anybody have any tips to fix this please?

This is the css used for the input -

```
 background: url(http://ourserver/qsBG.jpg) no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
background-color:transparent; 
border-style: none;

font-size: 14px;
height: 27px;
line-height: normal;
margin-left: 5px;
overflow: hidden;

vertical-align: bottom;
width: 282px;
```

Padding:0!important;
margin:0!important;
padding-top:5px!important;
padding-left: 24px!important;

Comment: What browser and if not the default Android browser, do you have that browser also on an iPhone/iPod with the same problem?

Comment: Hi - just android typical browser -- fine on iphone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I removed the overflow:hidden on the inputs and it fixed the problem. The same page didn't have a problem on iOS.